# Why doesn't Puzzling have a twitter?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

According to [employee JNat](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6558/community-promotion-ads-2019?cb=1#comment14636_6558), Puzzling does not have a Twitter:

> unfortunately Puzzling does not have a twitter account

Why not? Many of the other SE sites I'm a part of have Twitter, though truthfully I'm not sure which ones do and do not. What dictates whether a SE site gets a Twitter account or not? I figure they're not just managed by the community.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stack Exchange used to create a Twitter account for every site, but they stopped several years ago, as it was a hassle and was practically useless. According to Adam Lear (developer, former Community Manager at SE) on [Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/264548/294691):

> Not all sites have Twitter accounts. We stopped creating them for all public beta sites by default because a) Twitter sees very little engagement for us; b) Twitter-the-company started blocking new accounts for us (probably because it thinks we're bots?) and fighting that got too annoying and time-consuming.